# How to find a composition $\nabla$ such that $(E,\Delta)$ is isomorphic to $(E,\nabla)$ where $E=\{a,b\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have been given the set $E=\{a,b\}$ and I need to find out a composition $\nabla$ such that there exists automorphsim between $(E,\Delta)$ and $(E,\nabla)\,.$

There are two bijective functions from $E$ onto $E$. One is identity function $I_E$ and other is $J: J(a)= b;~J(b)=a\,.$

There are two cases; one is $\Delta = \nabla$ and other is $\Delta\ne \nabla\,.$ For the former, $I_E$ acs as the bijective mapping while for the latter case, $J$ acts as the bijective mapping.

But I'm unable to figure out what $\nabla$ would be.

My book says there exists four $\{\Delta, \nabla\}$ when $\Delta=\nabla$ and six $\{\Delta,\nabla\}$ when $\Delta\ne \nabla\,.$

Could anyone help me how to proceed further and conclude what the book is saying?

Comment: You just define $x\nabla y = J(x) \Delta J(y)$.

Comment: Yes @tobias, this is the very definition. But I also don't know what $\Delta$ is. I can make tables for the composition. But how many Cayley tables would be there for a composition? There would be finite but many. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: The tables are $2\times 2$, and there can be  any of two elements in each entry, so you have 16 different ones.

Comment: Okay @tobias. In my book, however, only four compositions were given for $\Delta$ with the author saying they are the compositions when $\Delta=\nabla\,.$ I don't get why the author didn't take the other twelve compositions.

Comment: You mean the other $12$? Anyway, does the book put other requirements on the compositions? Such as associativity or such?

Comment: Also, I have no idea what you mean by "the compositions when $\Delta = \nabla$".

Comment: @tobias, yes, I meant 12. Wait, I'll edit my post to clarify the point and add a snapshot of the page.

Comment: (Damn, mistakenly pressed the _discussion to chat_ link) I'm checking if there are other constraints on the problem @Tobias.

Comment: Actually, I think I see what it means now. So there are 4 for which the two operations are identical and 12 for which they are not, and these 12 are collected into 6 pairs of isomorphic ones with the isomorphism given by $J$.

Comment: That's it! I think I got my answer. I will prepare all the tables to verify it. If there is any problem, I'll ping you @Tobias.